# Is there a way to make the Opayo iframe accept autofilled card details from Google Pay?

Tags: opayo, google-pay

We're using the Opayo drop-in checkout to take card details in the Opayo iframe: https://developer-eu.elavon.com/docs/opayo/integrate-our-drop-checkout

The card expiry field in the iframe only accepts expiry dates in `MMYY` format and is limited to 4 characters

If a user autofills their card details from saved cards in their Google Pay account, Google Pay autofills with a `/`, resulting in an invalid entry of `MM/Y`

Anyone know of a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

I would raise a bug/feature request with Opayo.

Based on the view-source, it looks like they are trying to disable autofill (`autocomplete="off"`):

```html
<form id="card-details-form">
  <div class="form-group">
      <div class="label-column">
          <label>Name:</label>
      </div>
      <div class="input-column">
          <input name="cardholder-name" placeholder="Cardholder Name" maxlength="50" autocomplete="off" pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9àáâäãåąčćęèéêëėįìíîïłńòóôöõøùúûüųūÿýżźñçčšžÀÁÂÄÃÅĄĆČĖĘÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏĮŁŃÒÓÔÖÕØÙÚÛÜŲŪŸÝŻŹÑßÇŒÆČŠŽ∂ð /\\&amp;-.']{1,50}$" required="">
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
      <div class="label-column">
          <label>Card:</label>
      </div>
      <div class="input-column">
          <input type="tel" name="card-number" inputmode="numeric" placeholder="0000 0000 0000 0000" maxlength="20" autocomplete="off" pattern="^\d{12,20}$" required="">
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
      <div class="label-column">
          <label>Expiry:</label>
      </div>
      <div class="input-column">
          <input type="tel" name="expiry-date" inputmode="numeric" placeholder="MMYY" maxlength="4" autocomplete="off" pattern="^(0[1-9]|1[012])\d{2}$" required="" title="This field is required" class="invalid">
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
      <div class="label-column">
          <label>CVC:</label>
      </div>
      <div id="security-code-input-column" class="input-column">
          <input type="tel" name="security-code" inputmode="numeric" placeholder="123" maxlength="4" autocomplete="off" pattern="^\d{3,4}$" required="">
      </div>
      <span id="cvc-help" class="icon-background" data-help-dialog-id="d2189a80-12f9-4a03-bd6a-d34b8ccb01a7"></span>
      <div id="cvc-help-content" class="hidden">Card Verification Code, the 3-digit number printed on the back of your card. For American Express it's the 4-digit number on the front.</div>
  </div>
</form>
```

If Opayo need details on the benefits of autofill, here is a blog post from ebay that may help: https://tech.ebayinc.com/engineering/autofill-deep-dive/

Comment: Thank you for the reply – I've raised a ticket with Opayo support